# Synchronization iOS device and sony action cam HDR-AS200V. Get full movie with sound

Tags: ios, api, synchronization, sony

I have a little issue. How can I sync (at the same time to start recording at the iOS device and the action camera)? The fact that the camera doesn't support time in thousandths of a second... Also, can I take the recorded video from action camera on the iPhone in one file together with a soundtrack? (I can get only a lot of images). In advance thank you for the help. P.S// I have been used Sony_CameraRemoteAPIbeta_API-Reference_v2.20.

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no way to sync the recording of a movie on the phone and camera at the same time.  The API does provide a callback to let you know when the recording has started but is not precise to that level as you noted.

   2. Take a look at the getContentList API.  You can use that to retrieve the URL of a movie file.